# How to use Automapper IMappingAction with asp.net bolierplate?

Tags: c#, automapper, castle-windsor, aspnetboilerplate

Dears,
I used Automapper IMappingAction to encapsulate Before and After Map Actions into small reusable classes but i can't make my class work with **ASPNET Bolierplate Ioc Castle Windsor**

```
configuration.CreateMap<CustomerDto, Customer>()
 .AfterMap<CustomerAction>().ReverseMap();

public class CustomerAction : IMappingAction<CustomerDto, Customer>
{
    private readonly IObjectMapper _objectMapper;

    public CustomerAction(IObjectMapper objectMapper)
    {
        _objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }

    public void Process(CustomerDto customerDto, Customer customer)
    {

    }
}
```

when my code get execute, i got exception that my class doesn't have **parameterless constructor**

Comment: Here's a link to documentation that may help:  https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Dependency-Injection

Comment: I already read this document but i don't know how to integrate automapper with boilerplate ioc

Comment: Which class exactly doesn't have a parameterless constructor? And have you tried adding a constructor with no parameters to that class?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/aspnetzero/aspnet-zero-core/issues/1587#issuecomment-415617774

Do you try this?

```
cfg.CreateMap<CustomerDto, Customer>().AfterMap((source, destination) =>
{
    var action = IocManager.IocContainer.Resolve<CustomerAction>();
    action.Process(source, destination);
}).ReverseMap();

public class CustomerAction : IMappingAction<CustomerDto, Customer>, ITransientDependency
{
    private readonly IObjectMapper _objectMapper;

    public CustomerAction(IObjectMapper objectMapper)
    {
        _objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }

    public void Process(CustomerDto customerDto, Customer customer)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome @maliming ;) he cannot open AspNet Zero private repository link unless he has ongoing AspNet Zero license. but your answer seems correct. `ITransientDependency ` should work.